# how to format data class containing set of records thats within a list

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, set

I have a data class called Alert that contains the following

```
data class Alert(
    val status: String,
    val records: Set<String>
)
```

val orderedStatuses = getOrderedStatuses(date, statuses) returns a `List<Alert>` that currently holds 3 values each with its own set.

```
    val orderedStatuses = getOrderedStatuses(date, statuses)
    val alert = if (orderedStatuses.isEmpty()) {
        "No alerts found"
    } else {
        "${orderedStatuses.size} alerts found "+
            "Alerts:\n" +
                orderedStatuses.joinToString("\n") {
                "\t${it.status} : \n" +
                    "\t(${it.records})"
            }
    }
```

The output looks like this:

```
Alerts:
    error_foo : 
    ([000-00-0000-00-000000000000, 111-1111-111-111-111111111111])
    error_bar : 
    ([222-222-222-222-222222222222, 333-33-3333-33-333333333333])
    error_blah : 
    ([444-4444-44444-444-444444444444, 555-555-555-555-555555555555])
```

What I'm struggling to do is list the alerts in a format like the following

I want to fix the set to look like the following:

```
Alerts:
    ERROR_foo : 
    ('000-00-0000-00-000000000000', '111-1111-111-111-111111111111')
    Error_bar : 
    ('222-222-222-222-222222222222', '333-33-3333-33-333333333333')
    Error_blah : 
    ('444-4444-44444-444-444444444444', '555-555-555-555-555555555555')
```

I've been looking into functional programming with Kotlin but haven't found something that clicks in my head/works

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the way you print the alert, I think the one need to modify is this part

```
"\t(${it.records})"
```

should call another `joinToString()` and a little transformation, here is how you can call it

```
"\t(${
    it.records.joinToString(",") { record -> "'${record}'" }
})"
```

Here is the full code on the `else` block

```
"${orderedStatuses.size} alerts found " +
    "Alerts:\n" +
        orderedStatuses.joinToString("\n") {
            "\t${it.status} : \n" +
                "\t(${
                    it.records.joinToString(",") { record -> "'${record}'" }
                })"
        }
```

Comment: That worked! is there any way to remove the [ ]'s and around each individual set just to have it be like this: 
`('444-4444-44444-444-444444444444', '555-555-555-555-555555555555')`
instead of  this:
`[('444-4444-44444-444-444444444444', '555-555-555-555-555555555555')]`

Comment: The answer above already have output without `[]` anyway